# Multiple selection of images with add caption option

Tags: android

I'm working on one demo where I want to apply , Lib or anything  else which works like as whatsapp. I want on button click it will show all gallery images in thumbnail at the bottom of screen and after multiple section of image, then also provide option to add text on/ at the bottom of single single image.

Comment: you mean like an image picker ? there's quite a few that allows multiple selection https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157?page=1&sort=name

Comment: I want to add caption also . like as whatsapp app

Comment: to overlay captions, just use any image processing API there's quite a lot. https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6736